# Run a bash file in XCode project at time of building it in XCode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bash, xcode5

I've a bash (.sh file) which contains some modification I want to do while building my XCode project . How can I run that .sh script at time of builing ?

Answer (score 2):

1- In the project editor, select the target to which you want to add a run script build phase.

2- Click Build Phases at the top of the project editor.

3- Choose Editor > Add Build Phase > Add Run Script Build Phase.

4- Disclose the Run Script section in the project editor.

5- Configure the script in the Run Script template.

6- The screenshot shows a Run Script build phase that prints in the log navigator the name of the target being built.

[image]

You can use any of the shell languages available in your system.

Source: Apple documentation.

I hope that was helpful :)

Comment: ^^^ This is definitely the answer. You can check $CONFIGURATION == "Debug" or "Release" if you want to do different things based on build configuration. I use this method to generate a file (never included in my source repo) to include server information to point to my production server or dev box based on $CONFIGURATION. You'll want to make sure the Run Script is in the list of build phases where it makes sense (e.g. if you're generating a file that will be compiled, it'd better be before the compilation phase).